# Bloomberg API request timed out - Python

Tags: python, python-3.9, bloomberg, blpapi

I am a Bloomberg Terminal user and can't establish a connection with the Python Bloomberg API.

I was able to install the blpapi package like described on the Bloomberg help page and tried to import the xbbg package to get some data.

https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/

https://pypi.org/project/xbbg/

When I run this:

```
import blpapi
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdp(tickers='NVDA US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name'])
```

the following error message appears:

```
12APR2022_15:07:37.756 33312:20836 ERROR blpapi_metadatamanagerimpl.cpp:247 blpapi.session.metadatamanager.{1} Resolve request timed out { RequestId=NULL }  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DevLab\MyMainEnv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3361, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-83038899ddda>", line 5, in <cell line: 5>
    blp.bdp(tickers='NVDA US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name'])
  File "C:\DevLab\MyMainEnv\lib\site-packages\xbbg\blp.py", line 47, in bdp
    request = process.create_request(
  File "C:\DevLab\MyMainEnv\lib\site-packages\xbbg\core\process.py", line 47, in create_request
    req = srv.createRequest(request)
  File "C:\DevLab\MyMainEnv\lib\site-packages\blpapi\service.py", line 393, in createRequest
    _ExceptionUtil.raiseOnError(errCode)
  File "C:\DevLab\MyMainEnv\lib\site-packages\blpapi\exception.py", line 143, in raiseOnError
    _ExceptionUtil.raiseException(errorCode, description)
  File "C:\DevLab\MyMainEnv\lib\site-packages\blpapi\exception.py", line 135, in raiseException
    raise errorClass(description, errorCode)
blpapi.exception.InvalidArgumentException: Null service handle (0x00020002)
```

```
'blpapi' in sys.modules 
'xbbg' in sys.modules
```

gives me `True`

while

```
'blp' in sys.modules
```

gives me `False`

any ideas why this error occurs?

Comment: It's an odd place to have an error, if my reading of the trace is correct. The error suggests that `xbbg` has successfully connected and created a Bloomberg session, but the handle to the service (`//blp/refdata`) is Null. I think the "Resolve" part is where the client asks for a service by name, and the api tries to match this name with an available service on the server. This is quite a way down the 'food chain' ... it it were something simple, I would have expected higher-level errors to appear first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but some diagnostic code to isolate whether the error is coming from Bloomberg (`blpapi`) or the `xbbg` wrapper that uses this API.

It shows how to access Bloomberg data at the API level, without `xbbg`. If this code runs successfully then your Bloomberg connection is fine, and the problem is with xbbg, and vice-versa.

```
import blpapi

sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.setServerHost('localhost')
sessionOptions.setServerPort(8194)

session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

session.start()

if session.openService('//blp/refdata'):
    svc = session.getService('//blp/refdata')

    req = svc.createRequest('ReferenceDataRequest')

    req.append('securities','NVDA US Equity')
    req.append('fields','SECURITY_NAME')
    req.append('fields','GICS_SECTOR_NAME')

    session.sendRequest(req)

    results = None

    while(True):
        ev = session.nextEvent()

        if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
            for msg in ev:
                for elt in msg.asElement():
                    results = { e.getElementValue('security'): 
                                 { str(f.name()) : f.getValueAsString() 
                                     for f in e.getElement('fieldData') } 
                               for e in elt }
            break

    print(results)
```

The output should be:

```
{'NVDA US Equity': {'SECURITY_NAME': 'NVIDIA Corp', 'GICS_SECTOR_NAME': 'Information Technology'}}
```

This is essentially what xbbg is doing when you call `bdp()`, and tests whether the basic Bloomberg API is working.